# Can I import a handleChange function and bind it for use in any component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-props

I am trying to better modularize my code and one of the things I have been thinking about is whether it makes sense to import a `handleChange` function I use in my react app forms so that I don't recreate it every time i have a new form. However I am running into an issue when importing it and passing it as a prop to a child component. I am unsure if this makes sense or perhaps I should avoid this practice, some guidance would be greatly appreciated:

**forms.js**

```
//HANDLES CHANGES TO FORMS
export const handleChange = (event) => {
  console.log(event);
   this.setState({
       [event.target.name]: event.target.value
   });
}
```

**SaveCardForm.js**

```
...
import { handleChange } from '../../../helpers/forms';

class SaveCardForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            postal: '',
            errorMessage: null,
            paymentMethod: null,
            showPay: false,
            payStatus: false,
            successModal: false,
            customer: 'cus_*****',
        };
        this.handleChange = handleChange.bind(this);
    }
...
<Container fluid>
                <Row>
                    <Col style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                        <CardSection
                            customer = {this.state.customer}
                            handleChange = {this.handleChange} 
                        /> 
                        <br />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
...
```

**CardSection.js**

```
...
function CardSection(props) {
  console.log(props.customer)
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Form onSubmit={() => console.log('...')}>
            <Form.Group controlId="email">
              <Form.Control required placeholder="Email Address" name="email" type="email" onChange={props.handleChange} value={props.email} />
...
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at SaveCardForm.handleChange
```

Answer (score 0):

First, regarding the error. `this` is not passed down to `handleChange` function. So that is why you are getting the TypeError. You will either need to 1) pass in `this` in some variable form, or 2) pass in a bound function from `this.setState`.

so for your util (forms.js) you can do:

1. pass in context

```
//HANDLES CHANGES TO FORMS
export const handleChange = (event, myContext) => {
  console.log(event);
   myContext.setState({
       [event.target.name]: event.target.value
   });
}
```

or 2) pass in a function, or some callback you want to call

```
//HANDLES CHANGES TO FORMS
export const handleChange = (event, myCallBackAction) => {
  console.log(event);
   myCallBackAction({
       [event.target.name]: event.target.value
   });
}
```

This is probably what you would want if you want to resuse this handler with different components.